# Remove Segmented control's unwanted background `multiplied` color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm using this code to change the background color of the segmented control:

```
segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .blue
```

It's working with a little issue. There is an unwanted gray tint on the background:

---

**Left**: Blue for **foreground**

**Right**: Blue for **background**

[image: Demo1]

---

**Left**: White for **foreground**

**Right**: White for **background**

[image: Demo2]

So this cause `.white` background to appear as `.lightGray` or something. How can I get rid of this multiplied color?

Comment: There's a shadow that you see. You want to remove that shadow. There might be some dirty ways to remove it, like getting all subviews of a segmentedControl and eventually clip the shadow out. But why would you like to do that? Maybe we can think of a better way to solve your problem, if you can better describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thats not the shadow, the shadow is underneath the selected segment. But the color I’m talking about is on the entire unselected segment